# How do I bind to a class that is not in my model in asp.net mvc 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, binding

Normally when I design a form, the data I am expecting is part of the viewmodel for the page, and I can put the class in the controller method and the binding works.

However, I am adding a form in a partial view of a master page, so it is not specific to any one viewmodel.  I tried just making sure the ID of the form field would match up with what would have normally automatically been generated, but the object values are always null in my controller method.

Here is a snippet form my the partial view of my master page:

```
            <tr>
                <td >Current password:</td>
                <td><%= Html.Password("PasswordChange.OriginalPassword", "", new RouteValueDictionary { { "class", "required remote" } })%></td>
            </tr>            
            <tr>
                <td >New password:</td>
                <td><%= Html.Password("PasswordChange.NewPassword", "", new RouteValueDictionary { { "class", "required remote" } })%></td>
            </tr>
```

As you can see can imagine, PasswordChange is not a part of all of my view models (surely it's not necessary to inherit all of my viewmodels from a common base in order to use this form?).

My controller method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ChangePassword(PasswordChange PasswordChange)
        {
```

I hit the method, but PasswordChange.OriginalPassword and PasswordChange.NewPassword are always null.

I assume there is some easy way to do this, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the prefixes:

```
<tr>
    <td>Current password:</td>
    <td><%= Html.Password("OriginalPassword", "", new RouteValueDictionary { { "class", "required remote" } })%></td>
</tr>            
<tr>
    <td >New password:</td>
    <td><%= Html.Password("NewPassword", "", new RouteValueDictionary { { "class", "required remote" } })%></td>
</tr>
```

or if you want to keep a prefix, make sure you define this prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(
    [Bind(Prefix = "PasswordChange")] PasswordChange model
)
{
    ...
}
```

By the way you might also consider using child actions instead:

```
public class PasswordChangeController: Controller
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new PasswordChange();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

and then inside your masterpage instead of rendering a partial, render the child action:

```
<% Html.RenderAction("Index", "PasswordChange"); %>
```

and of course now you will have a strongly typed `~/Views/PasswordChange/Index.ascx` partial where you could generate your form and use the strongly typed versions of the helpers.

For more information about child actions you may take a look at Phil Haack's [`blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) on this topic.

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I think I just found the root problem.  :-(  See my answer.

Comment: This is the answer the OP asked for. The fact that he found another answer doesn't change that.

Comment: @DaveA I'm not really sure what your point is, but I am happy to upvote this answer.  My discovery was simply that I was doing everything in a workable way, except my properties were private.  The prefixes do not seem to have been the obstacle.  I will read up on ChildActions, thanks.

Comment: @pc1oad1etter, ur right. Maybe i'm projecting on you my distaste for a lot of bad questions today.

Answer (score 0):

My PasswordChange class's member's were not set as public.

@%$#$^#%&%

from

```
public class PasswordChange
    {
        public OriginalPassword { get; set; }
        public NewPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

to

```
public class PasswordChange
    {
        public string OriginalPassword { get; set; }
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
    }
```